# Is it possible to join two objects in Blender 2.8, but apply scales to only one of them?

Tags: scale

I am quite new to Blender, and would like to perform the following:

I have two objects, a bar, and a basement for the bar that belong together, and that I would like to reuse in a scene. However, when I scale the bar, it can have different heights, say 2, 3 or 4 meters. But the basement always stays the same, it never changes size. So is it possible to join an object like this, so that only one part of it is scalable?

Comment: I don't think there are standard options to scale part of one object in object mode. But in edit mode you can select just the bar (press L on any part of that mesh) , scale, and go back to Object mode. Or temporarily separate the objects, scale the bar, and rejoin.

Comment: Hello :). I believe it can be done with some blender magic ([Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/35559/robin-betts), or [Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) would probably know how). But just scaling in Edit mode seems like a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the mention but I am no magician :) By design you can't keep different scales into one object but in this case I think shape keys would be put to very good use. I can't find resources on BSE about creating shape keys but I'm sure there are many. In the meantime [here is the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html#workflow)